# Authentication using sfdxAuthUrl

Tags: salesforcedx, oauth2, connected-apps, sfdx-plugin, auth

Trying to authenticate via file, I was running into this error:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "name": "Syntax",
  "message": "./authFile.json: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0",
  "exitCode": 1,
  "context": "Store",
  "stack": "Syntax: ./authFile.json: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0\n    at Function.wrap (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\plugin-auth\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\sfError.js:61:25)\n    at Store.catch (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\plugin-auth\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:283:38)\n    at async Store._run (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\plugin-auth\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:106:13)\n    at async Config.runCommand (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\@oclif\\core\\lib\\config\\config.js:272:25)\n    at async run (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\@oclif\\core\\lib\\main.js:76:5)\nCaused by: Syntax: ./authFile.json: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0\n    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)\n    at _readFile (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\plugin-auth\\node_modules\\jsonfile\\index.js:25:16)\n    at async Store.getUrlFromJson (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\plugin-auth\\lib\\commands\\auth\\sfdxurl\\store.js:47:31)\n    at async Store.run (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\plugin-auth\\lib\\commands\\auth\\sfdxurl\\store.js:25:15)\n    at async Store._run (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\plugin-auth\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:102:40)\n    at async Config.runCommand (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\@oclif\\core\\lib\\config\\config.js:272:25)\n    at async run (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\@oclif\\core\\lib\\main.js:76:5)",
  "warnings": [],
  "commandName": "Store"
}
```

when running this:

```
sfdx auth:sfdxurl:store -f ./authFile.json -a devhub2 -d -s --loglevel=ERROR --json
```

So basically, what I've tried:
Generating URL from force:org:display

I've tried extracting the json into txt file, I've been getting the error that json is not valid for some reason even though every other file says it is.

After that I've found out I can switch to using text file in the store command, so I tried that and got this error instead:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "name": "INVALID_SFDX_AUTH_URL",
  "message": "Invalid SFDX auth URL. Must be in the format \"force://<clientId>:<clientSecret>:<refreshToken>@<instanceUrl>\".  Note that the SFDX auth URL uses the \"force\" protocol, and not \"http\" or \"https\".  Also note that the \"instanceUrl\" inside the SFDX auth URL doesn't include the protocol (\"https://\").",
  "exitCode": 1,
  "context": "Store",
  "stack": "INVALID_SFDX_AUTH_URL: Invalid SFDX auth URL. Must be in the format \"force://<clientId>:<clientSecret>:<refreshToken>@<instanceUrl>\".  Note that the SFDX auth URL uses the \"force\" protocol, and not \"http\" or \"https\".  Also note that the \"instanceUrl\" inside the SFDX auth URL doesn't include the protocol (\"https://\").\n    at Function.parseSfdxAuthUrl (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\plugin-auth\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\org\\authInfo.js:227:19)\n    at Store.run (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\plugin-auth\\lib\\commands\\auth\\sfdxurl\\store.js:30:47)\n    at async Store._run (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\plugin-auth\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:102:40)\n    at async Config.runCommand (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\@oclif\\core\\lib\\config\\config.js:272:25)\n    at async run (C:\\Users\\Andreja\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sfdx-cli\\node_modules\\@oclif\\core\\lib\\main.js:76:5)",
  "warnings": [],
  "commandName": "Store"
}
```

After that I've figured out that I am not getting any "real auth data" from :display, so I've created a connected app, and used it's clientId, clientSecret, and refreshToken for the url.

At this point, I was still getting the same error as above.

So, after a lot of research, not finding any solution to it online, I've tried plunging my own fingers into :store code. Now what perplexes me is this actually (I've had to cover the data, but you can clearly see it matches):
[image]

Apparently regex101 matches the url from the file, and yes, the text file contains only the url, no quotes or anything else, does it need certain type of formatting?

Does anyone know what I may be missing? I think I may need to run Oauth flow in a different way, and not just fire the connected app at it? But I don't know a way of achieving that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the formatting on my local device was changed somehow, and this caused the issue.

Once I pushed this on pipeline to save the work, the connection actually worked.

So creating the connected app with 'api; web; refresh token', and using client key, client secret and refresh token from said connected app actually did provide me with valid url.